# How can I access the sample code for several Activities in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I remember somehow being able to access the sample code that I think came with the standard Android Studio download. I can't access that now however, because I don't remember the location. I am referring to the files named "BasicMapDemoActivity", "ProgrammaticDemoActivity", "OptionsDemoActivity", etc. Any idea where I could find these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be where Android Studio installed the SDK to, which is now installed in a separate location from Android Studio.

Easiest way to figure this out is, in Android Studio, File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location, and it'll be in a clearly marked field.

Also, double check that you've actually installed the samples in your SDK manager.